# Trouble using UNION ALL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following to get data from database in a php file:

```
$query_pedVR = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY name ASC");
```

What I need to do is combine two tables in one query but can't seem to get it to work.  I have tried the UNION ALL, but can't find the syntax that works.  This isn't working:

```
$query_pedVR = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY name ASC");
```

Also tried:

```
$query_pedVR = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY name ASC UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2");
```

There are not any common entries in the two tables.  The two tables also have a different set of columns.

Is it possible to do this with different table structures?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Why the hell are you using `sprintf` for this?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: because there are a lot of programmers who don't even try to think about what they are doing. They just copy-paste the code and pray it works

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the purpose of this forum! I've received a lot of useful comments from programmers in the short time I have been a member.  What's the point of insulting people who are new to the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If tables have different structure you can't use `select *` but you must specify single fields

```
SELECT field1,field2 FROM table1 WHERE active = 1
union all
SELECT field1,field2 FROM table2 WHERE active = 1
```

Comment: I'd definitely point out that as long as tables contain different entities - there is no any reason to mix everything in one query

Comment: I didn't state the situation accurately enough.  There are several common columns in the two tables which are the ones I was trying to query for.  One table has additional entities which I don't need in this query.  I think your example is what I was looking for.  Thanks